# Java Reflection: Call abstract interface methods without instantiation

Tags: java, reflection, interface

I am currently facing problems integrating the existing Piketec TPT Java API (http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/piketec-tpt/com/piketec/tpt/api/package-summary.html) in a Java project by using Reflection.

The TPT Api provides an interface called "TptApi", which contains several abstract methods, that are used to access TPT projects.

I have already integrated other APIs such as the Dox4j-API, where a class instance was used as invokation target. Obvisouly, this is not the correct way for accessing method from an interface.

My goal is to access the method "OpenResult openProject(File f)" from the TptApi interface (http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/piketec-tpt/com/piketec/tpt/api/TptApi.html#openProject-java.io.File-).

My code:

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(...);
Map c = new HashMap();

File file = new File("test.prj");

c.put("TptApi", cl.loadClass("com.piketec.tpt.api.TptApi"));
c.put("OpenResult", cl.loadClass("com.piketec.tpt.api.OpenResult"));

//The way I did it with 'normal' classes, not applicable with the interface:
//Object target = ((Class) c.get("TptApi")).newInstance();

OpenResult or = (OpenResult)((Class) c.get("TptApi")).getMethod("openProject", new Class[]{File.class}).invoke(target, new Object[]{_file});
```

So how do I access abstract interface methods by Reflection?

Comment: Use method.invoke() of class Method from java.lang.reflect.       
e.g.                                                                                                      Class clazz = Something.class;
Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method : methods) {
    System.out.println(method.invoke());
}

Comment: A method to be executed must be concrete, not abstract. This means you need to give it an instance of a concrete class that supplies an implementation of the abstract method. Maybe you need to create a proxy...? Otherwise, what do you expect the behavior to be?

Comment: @gaurav: I use the invoke method, but I don't know what invokation target I should use, because I can't instantiate the interface.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele: The API only gives me access to the interfaces. It should be used to automatically open, modify and save TPT projects without using the TPT tool itself. So I want to use the method 'openProject' to open the defined TPT Project, afterwards modify its content and finally save the modified project. It is the only alternative to manipulating the project files on the file system, which is cumbersome.

Comment: In that case, the API developer has an implementation. What's missing is a way for you to obtain a reference to a concrete object. This is probably a question of documentation. Think about how EJB interfaces work (remote or local ejbs). It's probably the same thing. Maybe they use the service loader or similar patterns. Just check with the API developer to know how to use it.

Comment: Here's how you obtain a reference: [Utils.getTptApi](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/piketec-tpt/com/piketec/jenkins/plugins/tpt/Utils.html#getTptApi-hudson.model.AbstractBuild-hudson.Launcher-com.piketec.jenkins.plugins.tpt.TptLogger-hudson.FilePath:A-int-java.lang.String-long-)

Comment: 'Obviously, this is not the correct way for accessing method from an interface': rubbish. An abstract interface method *requires* an instance.

Comment: @EJP: Thank you for that explanation, I was trying to say that the 'newInstance' method seems to not work for interfaces, at least not in my project. This was no general statement.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: Thank you for the hint, I will try this method.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele: After your reply I have contacted the tool support and I am still waiting for a response.

Comment: I agree. `newInstance()` certainly does not work for interfaces, or abstract classes either. You need a concrete class that implements the interface. Otherwise your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over this Question so let me answer it even if it is a bit outdated. I read in your comments that you assume you do not need the TPT tool itselfe to use the API. That is simply wrong. The API is just a way to communicate via RMI with an open TPT instance. To connect to TPT the TPT instance must have enabled RMI and you have to know the configurable port and binding name. You can do that in the Preferences under "TPT API" or by starting TPT with command line arguments "--apiPort " and "--apiBindingName ". Now you can obtain the TptApi instance using these two lines of code:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(HOST, PORT); // get Server/RMI-Registry
TptApi remoteApi = (TptApi)registry.lookup(BINDING_NAME); // get TPT-API
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial post did not assume that TPT is not necessary for the usage of the API. It indeed is. The way how to enable the API in TPT is well-documented, the two lines of code you posted are also ok. The problem I described is to access the API **by using Java reflection**. For other APIs I could do this by using "newInstance" to get access to the tool. With TPT, the corresponding API object is an interface instead of a class, so there is no way to instantiate it. Therefore I wanted to know how this specific API can be accessed via reflection.